# Replace with regular String literal in all files in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

In my program we originally were using Java with Preview Features enabled, which gave as a feature to use String blocks defined in between three double quotes. For example:

```
String s = """
              Line one
              Line two
           """;
```

Now, we decided to go back to Java 14 and I need to replace those with regular String declaration in all project (which is around ~1000 occurrences). Is there a way to do that in bulk?

```
String s = "Line one\n"+
           "Line two\n";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run the inspection "Text block can be replaced with regular string literal" inspection on your code using the "Run Inspection by Name" action. It has a quick fix to do the conversion for you.